# error in installing android studio on mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

### Error in installing android studio

I have downloaded android studio 2.3 and I don't no to install. While installing it doesn't download SDKs and all.

It directly went to home page of android and I opened a project which does not have SDKs manager, AVD icons in it.

I think its a problem with the SDKs its taking the previous cache of android studio.. Please help me set up a proper environment..

Screen shot of my android studio:

[image]

Comment: Just a reality check: you are aware you have opened the root in the C drive as a project, right?

Comment: @Zoe Mac doesn't have C drive :)

Comment: Whatever the equivalent is, the root of the drive is opened. It's showing the entire computer instead of a single project

Comment: Yes, agree with you..there is no problem with setup..@Bhargavi you just need to open the project from file menu !!

Comment: Ok but why my sdk manager is not visible.. the toolbar has got a tick under view..

Comment: Thank you all i got it done by uninstalling eclipse which i had already in my system.. and tried installing android studio again.. It worked for me..!!